# Tokens are not being transferred with web3js

Tags: web3js, tokens, erc-20, nodejs

i have been using following code for transferring tokens from wallet to another with the use of web3js.

```
async Transfer(eth_address, amount){
  let tokenAddress = "0x6CbEDEc4F1ac9D874987D2769596544E0d9161ab";
  let sendAmount  = web3.utils.toWei(amount.toString(), 'ether')
  const consumerContract = new web3.eth.Contract(config.ERC20contractAbi, tokenAddress);
  const myData = consumerContract.methods.transfer(eth_address, sendAmount).encodeABI();
  const tx = {
    from,
    to:eth_address,
    value: '0',
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('25', 'gwei'),
    gas: 60000,
    chainId: 1,
    nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(from,'pending'),
    data: myData
  }
  const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey)
  const rawTx = signed.rawTransaction
  const sendRawTx = rawTx =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    web3.eth
      .sendSignedTransaction(rawTx)
      .on('transactionHash', resolve)
      .on('error', reject)
  )

  const result = await sendRawTx(rawTx).catch((err) => {
      return err
  })

  if(result.toString().includes('error')){
    return result
  }
  else{
    return result
  }

},
```

But now it is suddenly not working for me. I do receive transaction hash and it is also marked as success on etherscan.io. Here is the link
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa92a7181275474cd6bd00e6e220385230c0c275e98d63bc35570ba6c0f9c4ab9

As it can be observed that there is no information about token being transferred or not. I have been using same method for a while, i don't understand what i am doing wrong now. kindly Guide regarding this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the transaction data you used the recipient address as it were the token address.

```
  const tx = {
    from,
    to: tokenAddress,    // <---- You should use tokenAddress instead of eth_address
    value: '0',
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('25', 'gwei'),
    gas: 60000,
```

Comment: This is the answer I have been searching for for days. For the love of all that is holy help me bump it up...